# Writing variable value only in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to collect 4 values into variables, then write those values to the screen so it would look like this:

```
value1,value2,value3,value4
```

Instead, I'm getting the following:

```
@{name=value1},@{domain=value2},@{domainrole=value3},@{workgroup=value3}
```

Here's my code. Any feedback will be most appreciated. Thanks.

```
$name = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | select name
$domain = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | select domain
$domainrole = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | select domainrole
$workgroup = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | select workgroup
write-host "$name,$domain,$domainrole,$workgroup"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options to achieve this. One would be to use the parameter `-ExpandProperty` of `Select-Object` to turn objects with properties in string ... like this:

```
$name = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
$domain = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty domain
$domainrole = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty domainrole
$workgroup = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty workgroup
"$name,$domain,$domainrole,$workgroup"
```

Or you could keep the objects and acces their properties with the dot notation:

```
$name = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
$domain = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
$domainrole = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
$workgroup = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
"$name.name,$domain.domain,$domainrole.domainrole,$workgroup.workgroup"
```

I'd recommend the latter one because you can still use the objects for further steps in your code without loosing their properties. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very command question.  I like using foreach-object or % for short:

```
[pscustomobject]@{name='joe'} | % name

joe
```